# Scala List building

Tags: scala, collections, functional-programming, scala-collections

I am having trouble understanding Scala lists. I just want to create a list of lists:  *List(list(1,2), List(3,4))*
In the REPL I am trying:

```
val list= List()
val lt = List(1,2)
val ls = List(3,4)
list::lt resolves to - res0: List[Any] = List(List(), 1, 2) 
list::ls resolves to - res1: List[Any] = List(List(), 3, 4)
```

I'm coming from java and have never programmed functionally. I am just not getting it.

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: List(1,2):: List(3,4) :: Nil as explained by @som-snytt

Comment: You could also annotate types ecplicitly where the compiler can't infer the correct type on it's own. Like for `List()` which it infers as `List[Any]`. Just try: `List(List[Int](), List(1,2))` or: `List[List[Int]](List(),List(1,2))` or: `List(List.empty[Int],List(1,2))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to read [the book](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/next-steps-in-scala.html#step8), where it explains that cons `::` prepends to the thing on the right.

> one way to initialize new lists is to string together elements with
>   the cons operator, with Nil as the last element.

```
scala> List(1,2) :: Nil
res1: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2))
```

The book also explains about operators ending in a colon.

If you stick a `List[Nothing]` on the front of a `List[Int]`, you get the `List[Any]` you witnessed.

Comment: Thank you for your help!